# Tabbar visibility during navigation using NavigationStack on SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation

So I have the following root view:

```
struct TabBarView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack {
                TabBarFirstView()
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
            .tabItem {
                Label("first", systemImage: "list.dash")
            }
            NavigationStack {
                TabBarSecondView()
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
            .tabItem {
                Label("Second", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`TabBarSecondView` is not relevant, we will focus on `TabBarFirstView`:

```
struct TabBarFirstView: View {

    @State private var showSummaryView: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("TabBarFirstView")
            Button {
                showSummaryView = true
            } label: {
                Text("Show summary view")
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                Image(systemName: "list.dash")
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showSummaryView) {
            TabBarFirstSummaryView()
        }
    }
}
```

`TabBarFirstView` has the following destination: `TabBarFirstSummaryView`

```
struct TabBarFirstSummaryView: View {

    @State private var showDetailedView: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("TabBarFirstSummaryView")
            Button {
                showDetailedView = true
            } label: {
                Text("Show detailed view")
            }
        }
        .toolbar(.visible, for: .tabBar)
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showDetailedView) {
            TabBarFirstDetailedView()
        }
    }
}
```

`TabBarFirstSummaryView` has the following destination: `TabBarFirstDetailedView`

```
struct TabBarFirstDetailedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World! Details")
            .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
    }
}
```

So, as you see, in `TabBarFirstDetailedView` I want the toolbar to be hidden.
The problem that I'm facing is that when I press the top back button on `TabBarFirstDetailedView`, it takes about 1 second to have the tab bar displayed again on `TabBarFirstSummaryView`.
I'm not sure how can I have this working properly to have the tab bar always display on `TabBarFirstSummaryView` and avoid that animation, and even if you drag the `TabBarFirstDetailedView`, the tabbar on `TabBarFirstSummaryView` should be displayed.

I tried using `NavigationView` and `NavigationStack` and I have the same behavior, even on iOS 17.

Also, I don't see this behavior in any iOS app from Apple... or maybe is one I don't know about?

Comment: add onappear in TabBarFirstSummaryView and add codes that should force redraw.  It looks like that swiftui don't know they have to redraw whenever TabBarFirstSummaryView appears, since no state is changed.

Comment: The bar appears ... but after the pop animation finish...

Comment: Have the same issue.

Comment: Hi, is there any solution for this?